# How to shuffle testing order of packages in go?

Tags: go, testing

When I execute a command similar to this:

```
go test \
    github.com/mycompany/projectX/packageA \
    github.com/mycompany/projectX/packageB \
    github.com/mycompany/projectX/packageC
```

Then go will test packageA, then packageB, and then packageC. Is there an option so that the order of package testing is shuffled? For instance, packageC is tested first before package A then package B. There is a `-shuffle on` option but this option only shuffles the tests within a package. I want to shuffle the order of the packages.

Comment: why do you want to test the packages in different orders?

Comment: @Pizzalord I want to add stability to my test suite/environment over the long run. In my experience, when tests become so many, they become so tightly coupled to each other that adding new tests results to failures that are so hard to fix. I thought that in the long run, packages may somehow also become coupled to each other because of shared external dependencies such as a shared DB or redis server. (We use go for integration tests also, not just unit tests.) By having shuffled testing of packages, we can somehow detect and eliminate package test dependencies as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Packages are always tested in alphabetical order, no way to disable it. I wasn't there so I have to guess at the reason.

In general unit tests should not be dependent on the execution order since at that point you are testing more than just the functionality of your unit. If for some reason your unit tests are dependent on execution order, and this order is always fixed, you will still get consistent results. But if this order was somehow random or dependent on naming or order in which you specify them, than it means that a test may pass on your machine but fail in the CI or visa versa.

Such bugs are extremely frustrating since it might not be obvious that the order of tests influences its result.

Having said all that, if you wish you can still randomize testing using the [T.Run](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Run) method in a random order. But this only works within the same package not across packages.